# How to determine if a point is on a line in 4-dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Suppose there is the 4-dimensional Euclidean space $\cal{E}^4$. Let there be the line $\overset{\leftrightarrow}{l}$ that intersects the points $\left(x_1,y_1,z_1,u_1\right)$ and $\left(x_2,y_2,z_2,u_2\right)$.

How would one determine (in the realm of linear algebra) if the point $p$, defined as $\left(a,b,c,d\right)$, lies on $\overset{\leftrightarrow}{l}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a solution $t$ of the vector equation
$$(a,b,c,d) = (1-t) \cdot (x_1,y_1,z_1,y_1) + t (x_2,y_2,z_2,u_2)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate further? I am not sure what $t$ is. This is a new topic for me.

Comment: $t$ is a scalar parameter : the vector $P_1 A$ shall be parallel to $P_1 P_2$, i.e. $t$ times it

Comment: @GCab Thank you for your comment. I am currently taking linear algebra as a course and have not learned enough to understand your comment. It's weird because the professor suddenly assigned problems like this without any introduction to it.

Comment: @Oliver: then tell what you know about lines, otherwise we cannot help you ..

Comment: Sorry for never marking this as the answer. I have later realized this.